# Webpack-dev-server bundling React JS but not SCSS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, webpack-dev-server, sass-loader

App was made by "create-react-app" command. Bundled (by webpack) JavaScript code is working properly in my React App, but it does not seem to get any styling from SASS. There are no errors in console or anywhere, it's just being ignored. To start webpack I am running "npm run start". 
Repo just in case: https://github.com/ankeris/challengefriend

This is the code:

> package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development --hot | react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.22.1",
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
}
```

> webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
entry: './src/index.js',
output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
},
module: {
    rules: [
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
            "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
            "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
            "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
        ]
    },
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
    }
    ]
},
}
```

> index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import './styles/scss/index.scss';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: do you have any styles in `index.scss` ?

Comment: I do. -> ```@import 'body';
@import 'app';
@import 'canvas';

body {
    background-color: red;
}```

Comment: open the bundled file to see if you can see `body { background-color: red; }` inside

Comment: I do not see it there, it is just default browser body css: ```body {
    display: block;
    margin: 8px;
}```

Comment: I will add a repo https://github.com/ankeris/challengefriend

Comment: `react-create-app` doesn't use you webpack config (it has it owns config) that's why you don't see your styles

Comment: did u run npm run eject command?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc to add sass to create react app project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it worked, I followed this [link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc) it tells you how to add css preprocessor in `react-create-app`, here are the commands to run :

`npm install --save node-sass-chokidar`

`npm install --save npm-run-all`

then add these lines in your `package.json` (in the `scripts` section) :

```
"build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
"watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
"start-js": "react-scripts start",
"start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
"build-js": "react-scripts build",
"build": "npm-run-all build-css build-js",
```

in your file `index.js` replace `import './styles/scss/index.scss';` by `import './styles/scss/index.css';`

Finally you can start your app by running `npm start`

[image]

As I said in comment, `react-create-app` uses its own webpack config, so your `webpack.config.js` is useless you can remove it from your project

If you really want to import the `scss` file, then you need to modify the default `react-create-app` webpack config, you need to run `npm run eject` to extract the config, then modify the files `/config/webpack.config.{env}.js`

Comment: Yes, it is working indeed. It is important to understand that react-create-app uses its own webpack config behind the scene. However, "npm-run-all" is not needed to achieve the result, but helps with the productivity :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be loaders because you are using Webpack 4.

Please add below rule in Webpack and try

```
  {
       test: /\.scss$/,
       loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
  }
```

Comment: Does not work, I have tried both options (I think they both should work, otherwise webpack would throw an error)